# Batch – Findstr with error level condition, quotes?

Tags: loops, batch-file, quotes, lan, findstr

I have a batchfile script that I wrote as an interface for connecting to my network shares. At this point it’s very simple. It has a list of my shares that I would like to compare to network shares in use and disable that share as option if it’s found. The following code snippet is part of a for loop that iterates over the number of shares in the list and lists them.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set list[0]="\\xxx.xxx.x.xx\photo"
set list[1]="\\xxx.xxx.x.xx\photo 2"
for /l %%n in (0,1,2) do (
rem wmic netuse get remotename |findstr /C:!list[%%n]!
rem if %errorlevel% neq 0 do(command 1) else (command 2)
echo  %%n   !list[%%n]! 
)
```

The `rem` above is removed for testing the problem.
The thought here is to use `if %errorlevel%` condition to catch the match. The shares are echoed with double quotes. If for example photo is mounted, both photo and photo 2 will be matched which is undesirable.
Since the shares have similar names and added number with space I need to compare the strings exactly so I have tried with `findstr /x` switch but this doesn’t work at all. Not sure if the entry with double quotes interferes. Removing the double quotes in the list yields an error that number after the space cannot be opened. Am I approaching this in a correct way?

Comment: Delayed Expansion must also be used the with the `%errorlevel%` variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected)

Comment: Within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block") any `%var%`, including `%errorlevel%`, is replaced by the then-current ("parse time") value of that variable when the block syntax is being validated, hence `delayedexpansion` and `!var!` needs to be used to access the *current* value of the variable, including *errorlevel*. The syntax `if [not] errorlevel n` may also be used, meaning `if the errorlevel is [not] "n" OR GREATER THAN "n"`. Also, assigning quoted strings to variables make the variables hard to combine logically. Inserting quotes as needed is far simpler.

Comment: BTW: Delayed expansion would not be needed at all if you change the for loop to `for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('set list[') do %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe netuse get remotename | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:%%i && command 2 || command 1`. See [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564). I suggest to run in command prompt window also `findstr /?` and read the output help, especially about usage of the options `/G`, `/V` and `/L`. The task could be done most likely even more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

May I suppose a slightly different approach?

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "list[0]=\\xxx.xxx.x.xx\photo"
set "list[1]=\\xxx.xxx.x.xx\photo 2"
for /l %%n in (0,1,2) do (
  net use |findstr ilc:"  !list[%%n]!  " >nul && (
    echo found "!list[%%n]!", do command1
  ) || (
    echo no match for "!list[%%n]!" do command2
  )
)
```

Changes to your code:

- using `net use` instead of `wmic`, as `wmic` outputs Unicode, which we would have to handle.  And `net use` is a lot faster.
- using conditional operators `&&` and `||` instead of `errorlevel`
- made `findstr` more secure and
- discarded `findstr`'s output.
- corrected the `set` syntax to not include the quotes to the values.